# Prove that for any $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$, $\sqrt{a^2+b}=a+\frac{b}{2a+\frac{b}{2a+...}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that for any natural numbers $a$ and $b$,   $$\sqrt{a^2+b}=a+\frac{b}{2a+\frac{b}{2a+...}}.$$

This question is taken from Spivak's Calculus Chapter 22 on Infinite sequences, Problem 22-7(c).  Part (b) proves the continued fraction expansion for $\sqrt{2}$.  I cannot seem to generalize.

EDIT:  Some answers are assuming that the limit exists, however proving that the limit exists is the part I really need a solution for.

Comment: What happens if you square both sides?

Comment: @MichaelLee can you really do that for infinite fraction?

Comment: Why not? The answers below all denote the infinite fraction as having a defined value. If it makes you feel better, write $x$ instead and back-substitute later.

Comment: @MichaelLee I edited my post, though the question doesn't explicitly ask I need a proof that such a limit exists in the first place.  That was what was done in part (b) for root 2.

Comment: Sure. See Theorem 5.2 [here](http://wstein.org/edu/2007/spring/ent/ent-html/node65.html) for a general proof of convergence of continued fractions.

Comment: Just on a quick note, you can similarly say that: $$\sqrt{a^2 + b} = a + \mathop{\LARGE\mathrm K}^{\infty}\frac{b}{2a}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us set

$$\tag{1}A:=2a+\frac{b}{\left( 2a+\frac{b}{2a+…}\right)}$$

Thus the equality to be established is $\sqrt{a^2+b}=A-a \ (?)$, i.e., $$\tag{2}A=a+\sqrt{a^2+b} \ \ \ \ (?)$$

But, the "generalized continued fraction" in (1) can be expressed under the form:

$$\tag{3}A=2a+\frac{b}{A}$$

which gives a quadratic equation $A^2-2aA-b=0$ in variable $A$, whose positive solution is (2).

---

**Edit:** the convergence of the continued fraction follows from a reasoning on the sequence defined (see (3)) by

$$\tag{4}A_{n+1}:=\varphi(A_n)$$

with $\varphi(x):=2a+\frac{b}{x}$ and any positive $A_0$.

Let us recall that this **fixed point** convergence is guaranteed through the classical inequation, consequence of the Mean Value Theorem :

$$|\underbrace{\varphi(A_n)}_{A_{n+1}}-\underbrace{\varphi(A)}_A|< M |A_n-A|$$

where $M=\sup_{x \in V}|\varphi'(x)|$ (V arbitrary small vicinity of limit $A$) under the condition that $M<1$.

Indeed :

$$\tag{5}|\varphi'(x)|=\frac{b}{x^2} < 1$$

Thus, for $A$ being given by (2), it is sufficient to check that:

$$\tag{6}|\varphi'(A)|=\frac{b}{(a+\sqrt{a^2+b})^2} < 1 \ \ \  \ (?)$$

(the existence of vicinity $V$ of $A$ is guaranteed by the continuity of $\varphi$).

(6) is true, by equivalence with $(a+\sqrt{a^2+b})^2>b$, an inequality that is easily verified (if $a>0$ of course).

Comment: Thanks but can you prove that the continued fraction as an infinite sequence has a limit in the first place.  That is the difficult part.

Comment: I just added the proof of existence of the limit.

Comment: I am not familiar with the math you are doing about the 'fixed point' convergence.  But I do have some idea of what is going on.  At (5) you say that if $|\varphi'(x)|$ is less than 1 then the sequence converges, can I ask what is the actual theorem that this relies on?

Comment: Because inequation $|\underbrace{A_{n+1}-A}_{e_{n+1}}|< M |\underbrace{A_n-A}_{e_n}|$ implies that the $n$th error $e_n<M^n e_0$ thus tend to 0 because $M<1$.

Comment: Behind this, we have the MVT (mean value theorem). see (https://www3.nd.edu/~zxu2/acms40390F12/Lec-2.2.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Denote $X:=2a+\cfrac{b}{2a+\cfrac{b}{2a+\ddots}}$. Then, we have,

$$X-a=a+\frac bX$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: It would be even clearer if you wrote $X= 2a +\frac{b}{X}$. Good idea nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

You get the continued fraction as limit of $x_{n+1}=a+\frac{b}{a+x_n}$, $x_0=a$, if that limit exists. As rational iterations are not that easy to analyze, linearize them by setting $p_0=a$, $q_0=1$, and separate numerator and denominator in
$$
\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}=a+\frac{b}{a+\frac{p_n}{q_n}}=a+\frac{bq_n}{aq_n+p_n}
=\frac{ap_n+(a^2+b)q_n}{aq_n+p_n}
$$
to get the linear iteration

$$
\begin{bmatrix}p_{n+1}\\q_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}a&a^2+b\\1&a\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}p_n\\q_n\end{bmatrix}
$$

with eigenvalues $ a\pm\sqrt{a^2+b}$ and eigenvectors $[\sqrt{a^2+b},\pm 1]^T$.

The resulting sequence of partial fractions is thus
$$
x_n=\sqrt{a^2+b}\cdot\frac{(a+\sqrt{a^2+b})^{n+1}+(a-\sqrt{a^2+b})^{n+1}}{(a+\sqrt{a^2+b})^{n+1}-(a-\sqrt{a^2+b})^{n+1}}
$$
and as $|a+\sqrt{a^2+b}|>|a-\sqrt{a^2+b}|$, this always converges to $\sqrt{a^2+b}$.

Answer (score 0):

We can write 
$$\sqrt{a^2 +b} + a = 2a + \sqrt{a^2+b}-a= 2a + \frac{ a^2+b -a^2}{\sqrt{a^2 + b} + a}=2a + \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b}+ a}$$

This may be enough for a proof.